# How to print double quotes (") in c# console application

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, console-application

I know that c# just prints the data inside double quotes:

```
Console.WriteLine("These two double quotes are removed when i am printed");`
```

And the output of it in console will be:

> These two double quotes are removed when i am printed

But what I want to print on console is the same thing with double quotes:

> "These two double quotes are removed when i am printed"

How do I do this. I am trying so because i have to write this output to a file where double quotes have significance.

Comment: those are not semi-colons.

Comment: Escape them: `"like \" that"` or `@"like "" that"`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to escape the characters using `\`:

```
Console.WriteLine("\"These two semi colons are removed when i am printed\"");
```

Also, the characters you are referring to (`"`) are not semi-colons but quotation marks. A semi-colon is `;`.

Answer (score 5):

Just add `\`. See the [String literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) article

```
Console.WriteLine("\"These two semi colons are removed when i am printed\"");
```